# Discord.js v14 Wholesome image erroring (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been trying to make a wholesomeimg cmd for my discord server, but it for some reason doesn't fetch the json correctly.

I tried this code:

```
if (message.content === "m.sendwholesomeimg") {
      if (message.member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.ManageGuild) || message.author.id === "1015205495780413480") {
        const url = await fetch("https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/random/.json");
        const random = await url.json();
        await message.guild.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.name.toLowerCase() === `・wholesome`).send(`${random[0].data.children[0].data.url}`);
      } else {
      message.reply('You do not have permission to use this command.')
    } 
  }
```

But it turned up with this error:

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.json (/nix/store/qpnf0dafrfsbcwb4z7cphjm0dff0vl7l-prybar-nodejs-0.0.0-e0d9a52/prybar_assets/nodejs/node_modules/@replit/node-fetch/index-3a548b1a.js:635:15)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:394:10)

Node.js v18.12.1
```

Comment: Looks like it fetched HTML, possibly because of some error. Can you `console.log(url)` before the `const random =....` line so that we can see?